# Category block in products layout

Tags: magento

I want show the cmsblock linked to category, in product layout, member to same category.
I set the block in catalog>manage category>diplay setting>cms block.
But i don't know how show it in products member of this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('cms/block')
            ->setBlockId(Mage::registry('current_category')->getLandingPage())
            ->toHtml();
?>
```

You need to insert this code into your /catalog/product/view.phtml template.

Comment: I have put code in template.phtml with rigth var and have sound good!

Comment: But if product not is member of category with block have error in page.